# Can not connect to wifi after newest upgrade ubuntu kernel generic

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, upgrade

My laptop used to connect wifi nornal. After I upgrade it to newest kernel, it cannot connect to wifi. My laptop detail below:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)


haniz@Cons:~$ ifconfig 
enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:e6:e2:52:72:bd  
          inet addr:192.168.0.52  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fdfc:ca84:e922:1:f804:182d:79ec:ba3/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fdfc:ca84:e922:1:2674:4ffa:d956:93df/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::7724:baca:c44:6353/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6519 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6171 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4415609 (4.4 MB)  TX bytes:791225 (791.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1283 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1283 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:125722 (125.7 KB)  TX bytes:125722 (125.7 KB)





haniz@Cons:~$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.


haniz@Cons:~$ uname -a
Linux Cons 4.8.0-53-generic #56~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 16 01:18:56 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Someone help me, please! Thanks

========================

## **Update: I solved.**

Maybe for some whatever reasons in installing. So I remove newest header-kernel and use `software` to upgrade instead of terminal.

Comment: did you install the wifi drivers?

Comment: of course, I did and use normal in previous ubuntu kernel version. However I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the /boot filesystem is not full or was full at the time you tried to install the latest kernel.